# Ошибка при добавлении строки в sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Когда я пытаюсь добавить строку с кавычками в базу данных, мне выдает ошибку:

> near "тормозят": syntax error

Сам код (самое важное)

```
import sqlite3

stroka = 'системы защиты "тормозят", поэтому аккаунты живут долго'

images = sqlite3.connect('images.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = images.cursor()
cur.execute(f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a98342(url, msg)')
images.commit()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO a98342(msg) VALUES(f"{stroka}")')
images.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вашу строку заменить на этот:

```
stroka = "системы защиты \"тормозят\", поэтому аккаунты живут долго"
```

Comment: К сожалению, мне обязательно, чтобы строка выглядела именно так. Я знаю как это решить, если бы это было не обязательно :(
Насчет кавычки со скобкой изменил, моя оплошность, писал от руки

Comment: в базу оно в любом случае будет записываться так: `системы защиты "тормозят", поэтому аккаунты живут долго`, но я не уверен)